# To load ES module set type="module"

Tags: node.js

[image]

I update the latest version of node also implement type="module" in package.json and also run node --expermentials-modules index.js. Still not working

Comment: Please post the error mesage in your question directly instead of posting an image of the error. Also please specify the version of node that you are using

Comment: I am using 12.18.2 version of node   .....and showing the error that  " Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: ES modules aren't available in nodejs version 12.18.2. You need to upgrade to the latest version of node which is currently 14.13.0